# Custom Classes data annotations

Tags: data-annotations

I have a custom class as:

```
public class BasicInfo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cell # is required.")]
    public string CellNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    public int Email { get; set; }

}

public class PErson
{
    public BasicInfo bInfo { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo cInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and using this code to validate - taken from: [How does one do property validation of a C# class using Data Annotations in .NET Framework 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285988/how-does-one-do-property-validation-of-a-c-sharp-class-using-data-annotations-in)

```
public static class Validator
{

    // This could return a ValidationResult object etc
    public static IEnumerable<string> Validate(object o)
    {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = o.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            object[] customAttributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), inherit: true);

            foreach (var customAttribute in customAttributes)
            {
                var validationAttribute = (ValidationAttribute)customAttribute;

                bool isValid = validationAttribute.IsValid(propertyInfo.GetValue(o, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null));

                if (!isValid)
                {
                    yield return validationAttribute.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works when my class is:

```
public class PErson
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cell # is required.")]
    public string CellNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    public int Email { get; set; }
}
```